Ideal Class Group of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3})$
I'm trying to compute the ideal class group of $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$, and I would like to know if my calculations are right and if I could improve my arguments.
Let $K=\mathbb Q(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$ be a field, with ring of integers $\mathcal O_K$.
We have $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}): \mathbb{Q}]=2$. Also, $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3}): \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})]\le2$. If it was $1$ we would have $\sqrt{3} \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$, which is impossible: $(a+b \sqrt{2})^2=3$ implies $a b=0$, contradiction.
By the tower law, $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3}): \mathbb{Q}]=4$.
So there must be $4$ embeddings $\sigma_i: K \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$. They all map $\sqrt{2}$ to $\pm \sqrt{2}$ and $\sqrt{3}$ to $\pm \sqrt{3}$, and moreover this information completely determines $\sigma_i$. Thus all four possibilities occur and are distinct.

Consider $\theta:=\frac{\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{6}}2$. Observe that $\theta\in\mathcal{O} _ K$, since $m_\theta(X)=X^4-4 X^2+1$.
Since $1, \sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3}, \theta$ are linearly independent over $\mathbb{Q}$, and $[K:\mathbb Q]=4$, then $1, \sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3}, \theta$ is a $\mathbb{Q}$-basis for $K$.

Suppose $γ=\frac12(a+b\sqrt{3}+c\sqrt{2}+d\sqrt{6}) ∈\mathcal{O}_K$, where $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{Q}$.
$\operatorname{Tr}_ {K / ℚ(\sqrt{2})}(γ)=a+c \sqrt{2}$
and
$\operatorname{Tr}_ {K / ℚ(\sqrt{3})}(γ)=a+b \sqrt{3}$
and
$\operatorname{Tr}_{K / ℚ(\sqrt{6})}(γ)=a+d \sqrt{6}$ are algebraic integers.
Since $2,3,6\not\equiv1\pmod4$, we have $a, b, c, d ∈ ℤ$.

$\operatorname{Norm}_{K / ℚ(\sqrt{3})}(γ)=\frac{1}{4}(a^2+3b^2-2c^2-6d^2)+\frac{1}{4}(2 a b-4c d) \sqrt{3}$ is an algebraic integer.
Since $3 \not≡ 1\pmod4$, it follows that $a^2+3 b^2 ≡ 2 c^2+6 d^2\pmod4$ and $2 a b ≡ 0\pmod4$.
The second equation gives that $a$ or $b$ is even, and then the first equation forces both to be even, so that $c^2+3 d^2 ≡ 0\pmod2$ forcing $c ≡ d\pmod2$.
It follows that every $γ ∈\mathcal{O}_ K$ is in $\langle 1,\sqrt2,\sqrt3,\theta\rangle_{\mathbb Z}$.
Hence $1,\sqrt2,\sqrt3,\theta$ is a $\mathbb Z$-basis for $\mathcal O_K$.
$\sqrt3=\theta^2-2\in\mathbb Z[\theta]$.
$m_\theta(0)=1\implies\theta^{-1}\in\mathbb Z[\theta]$.
$\sqrt2=(1+\sqrt3)\theta^{-1}\in\mathbb Z[\theta]$.
Hence $1,\theta,\theta^2,\theta^3$ is a $\mathbb Z$-basis for $\mathcal O_K$.

$\text{Disc}(K)=\text{Norm}_{K/\mathbb{Q}}(m_\theta'(\theta))=\text{Norm}_{K/\mathbb{Q}}(4\theta^3-8\theta)=4^4\text{Norm}_{K/\mathbb{Q}}(\theta)\text{Norm}_{K/\mathbb{Q}}(\theta-\sqrt2)\text{Norm}_{K/\mathbb{Q}}(\theta+\sqrt2)=4^4m_\theta(0)m_\theta(\sqrt2)m_\theta(-\sqrt2)=4^4\times1\times(-3)\times(-3)=2304$
The Minkowski bound is $\frac{4!}{4^4}\sqrt{2304}=\frac92<5$. Thus every nontrivial ideal class contains a prime ideal of norm $2$ or $3$. Every ideal contains its norm, thus we need to factor $(2),(3)$ into prime ideals.

$m_\theta(X)=(X+1)^4\bmod2$. By Dedekind, $(2,1+\theta)$ is a prime ideal, and
$$(2)=(2,1+\theta)^4$$
so $N((2,1+\theta))=2$.
$\text{Norm}_{K/\mathbb Q}(1+\theta)=m_\theta(-1)=-2$, so $N((1+\theta))=2$.
$(2,1+\theta)\mid(1+\theta)$ and have the same norm, so $(2,1+\theta)=(1+\theta)$.

$m_\theta(X)=(X^2-2)^2\bmod3$. By Dedekind, $(3,\theta^2-2)$ is a prime ideal, and
$$(3)=(3,\theta^2-2)^2$$
$\theta^2-2=\sqrt3$, so $(3,\sqrt3)=(\sqrt3)$.
All of the prime ideals lying above $2,3$ are principal, thus $\text{Cl}(K)$ is trivial and $\mathcal O_K$ is a PID.

By the class number formula the class group is trivial. For a similar (but different) case of $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{-3})$ see this post. Otherwise your proof looks right to me, at first sight.
